# Delphi FMX (Android) - How read text file inside zip stream without extract?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, zip

Is it possible to read a file from the zip file without extract it? I want to read a text file from a compressed file(as an android assets) in a Memo lines.

```
ZipFile := TZipFile.Create; //Zipfile: TZipFile
try
 ZipFile.Open('C:\Path\to\file.zip', zmRead);
  for I := 0 to ZipFile.FileCount - 1 do
begin
if ZipFile.FileNames[I]='A1.txt' then //S: string
//My problem is here ? How load A1.txt to memo lines?
Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
end;
ZipFile.Close;
finally
ZipFile.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TZipFile` has public [`Read()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Zip.TZipFile.Read) methods that allow you to obtain either a `TBytes` of the complete decompressed file, or a `TStream` for reading the decompressed bytes dynamically.  You can use those bytes to write to the `TMemo` as needed.

For instance, using a `TStream`, you can read bytes from the file into a local buffer until you encounter a line break, and then add the buffer to the `TMemo` and clear the buffer, repeating until you reach the end of the `TStream`.

Note that, in either case, you would be accessing the *raw* bytes of the text file, whereas `TMemo` expects Unicode strings, so you would have to convert the bytes to Unicode, such as with `SysUtils.TEncoding`, based on the actually encoding of the text file.  For instance, using `TEncoding.UTF8` if the text file is UTF-8 encoded.  `TEncoding` has `GetString()` methods for converting `TBytes` data to `UnicodeString`.